# 50W LED with 10W power equal to 10W LED at full power?

Tags: led

If I buy a 50W LED and power it at 10W will it have the same brightness as a 10W LED at full power?

Comment: High power LED's are usually constructed of several series/parallel combinations of LED strings. They often need voltage levels much higher than a 'normal' LED. A 100W LED 'COB' that I have needs 36V at 3 amps or so for full power. If I reduced the voltage by 50% to cut the power to 50 watts the device might not even light up, and if it does the array of LED's will certainly be of uneven brightness...

Comment: @bobt: der, nope. LEDs are current driven devices, so you can easily run them with a powerful limited constant current source (any useful smu will do that for you) and run them at whatever wattage you like and they will start outputting light at usually well under a thousandth of their nominal current.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All else being equal, yes. Of course, all things are never equal.

First, the lower-power unit will probably be physically smaller than the 50 watt, and this will include the light-emitting area. If you look directly at the LED while it operates, there is a good chance that the lower-power unit will appear brighter, since it is emitting light from a smaller area. However, the appearance is irrelevant. What counts is the total light emitted, not the power density per unit area.

Second, (again assuming a physically smaller LED) heat sinking is likely to be more effective on the higher-power LED. At the same power it is likely that the low power LED will run hotter, and this will reduce its efficiency somewhat.

Finally, the power rating for an LED refers to the total input power, not the visible output. So the two LEDs may not use the same process, and may have different intrinsic efficiencies.

Comment: +1 btw, regarding the last bit, what if the two said LEDs are marketed as having the same lumens/watt?

Comment: @NVZ - In that case, the last consideration does not apply.

Answer (score 7):

It'll be brighter by a fair bit, because you are running it under its rating.  LEDs are more efficient when you do. Here's a typical efficiency curve.

[image]

Voltage is changing very slightly with current, so you have to break out the sharp pencil if you want exact numbers.  But the voltage doesn't change enough to matter.  In this example, suppose we run it at 400ma and get 1.65x reference light output.  That's an efficiency of 4.125 units per amp.  But run it at 80ma instead (80% less), and get 0.45x reference light output. That's an efficiency of 5.625 units per amp. That's 36% better amp-efficiency.  There'll be a small voltage difference, so *watt* efficiency won't be quite as good, but it'll certainly be 25% better.

Since you're holding power constant, you can expect in the neighborhood of 25% more usable brightness from the larger emitter.

This doesn't scale infinitely; running 1% of capacity (1000W LED at 10W) won't give you even more efficiency. There are sane limits. But there's also a "sweet spot" - and running at 20% is pretty close to the sweet spot.